# Can not show image after attach in UITextView in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, uikit, uitextview

I want to insert image to uitextview like note application in iphone. I successfully insert images but when I save the note, I can not show images that I inserted when click to see detail of the note. How can I fix that?
[The note before saving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTQfP.png)
[The note after saving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqfQe.png)

Here is my code:
[Add image after choosing from library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avd9S.png)
[Initial set up when navigate to detail view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37P56.png)

Comment: Please copy/paste code, not only screenshots

Answer (score 0):

```
private func setup() {
        tfTitle.layer.borderWidth = 1
        tfTitle.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        tfTitle.text = note.title
        tvContent.layer.borderWidth = 1
        tvContent.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        tvContent.text = note.content
//        var attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString!
//        attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self.tvContent.attributedText)
//        tvContent.attributedText = attributedString
//        tvContent.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: note.content)
//        tvContent.textStorage.insert(NSAttributedString(string: note.content), at: 0)
    }
  
    //Insert the image    
        func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
                    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    results.forEach { result in
                        result.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { object, error in
                            if let image = object as? UIImage, error == nil {
                                self.images.append(image)
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    let attachImage = self.images[self.images.count - 1]                        
                                    //Caculate new size
                                    let newImageWidth = (self.tvContent.bounds.size.width)
                                    let scale = newImageWidth/image.size.width
                                    let newImageHight = image.size.height*scale
                                    
                                    let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
                                    attachment.bounds = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: newImageWidth, height: newImageHight)
                                    attachment.image = attachImage
                                    
                                    var attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString!
                                    attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self.tvContent.attributedText)
                                    
                                    let attachString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
            //                        self.tvContent.textStorage.insert(
            //                            attachString,
            //                            at: self.tvContent.selectedRange.location)
                                    attributedString.append(attachString)
                                    self.tvContent.attributedText = attributedString
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Edit your question with your code, not in a answer if it's not solving your issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In **func setup()** you need generate attributeString with saving image in attachment.

```
let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
attachment.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newImageWidth, height: newImageHeight)
attachment.image = attachImage // saving from cache or storage memory
var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: "your note text")
attributedString.append(NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment))
self.tvContent.attributedText = attributedString
```

BUT: If you are storing a whole attributedString in note.content. Just then pass it self.tvContent.attributedString

Comment: I am storing attributedString in note.content as String type. So What does "Just pass it self.tvContent.attributedString" mean? I don't understand clearly.

Comment: If you storing only string, you need save image too and add string in image in attributedString from setup.